# Flow of authorize attribute in rest API controller for debugging using OAuth and OWIN and identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, owin

Hi i am making a rest web api project in which i selected individual user account.
By Default its created account controller and ApplicationOAuthProvider and Startup.Auth.cs .

And Values controller is decorated with [Authorize] attribute which is authorizing request using bearer token is valid or not.

So i want to know answer of below question

- what is the flow of Authorize attribute, how Authorize attribute flow
  decide that token is valid or expire. where or in which class and
  method its check that. for example i am making a request with bearer
  token how my application decide that it is valid token or its expiry
  in any class
- how i can capture bearer token in database and based on this token
  and its expiry i want to customize authorize attribute on
  authorization policy like if token is valid in database i need to do some operation

i am using visual studio 2017 and latest owin packages

my Startup.Auth.cs class

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
        //OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        //{
        //    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/Login"),
        //    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        //    RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
        //    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        //    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        //};
        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "",
        //    appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        //{
        //    ClientId = "",
        //    ClientSecret = ""
        //});
    }



}
```

my ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _publicClientId;

    public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        _publicClientId = publicClientId;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    //public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    //{
    //    string clientId;
    //    string clientSecret;
    //    if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
    //    {
    //        if (clientSecret == "secret")
    //        {
    //            context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:client_id", clientId);
    //            context.Validated();
    //        }
    //    }
    //    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    //}

    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
        {
            Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", userName }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
}
```

and  Account controller

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
        ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> AccessTokenFormat { get; private set; }

    // GET api/Account/UserInfo
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
    [Route("UserInfo")]
    public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
    {
        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        return new UserInfoViewModel
        {
            Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
            HasRegistered = externalLogin == null,
            LoginProvider = externalLogin != null ? externalLogin.LoginProvider : null
        };
    }

    // POST api/Account/Logout
    [Route("Logout")]
    public IHttpActionResult Logout()
    {
        Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        //HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
       // Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();

       // Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return Ok();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ManageInfo?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
    [Route("ManageInfo")]
    public async Task<ManageInfoViewModel> GetManageInfo(string returnUrl, bool generateState = false)
    {
        IdentityUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if (user == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        List<UserLoginInfoViewModel> logins = new List<UserLoginInfoViewModel>();

        foreach (IdentityUserLogin linkedAccount in user.Logins)
        {
            logins.Add(new UserLoginInfoViewModel
            {
                LoginProvider = linkedAccount.LoginProvider,
                ProviderKey = linkedAccount.ProviderKey
            });
        }

        if (user.PasswordHash != null)
        {
            logins.Add(new UserLoginInfoViewModel
            {
                LoginProvider = LocalLoginProvider,
                ProviderKey = user.UserName,
            });
        }

        return new ManageInfoViewModel
        {
            LocalLoginProvider = LocalLoginProvider,
            Email = user.UserName,
            Logins = logins,
            ExternalLoginProviders = GetExternalLogins(returnUrl, generateState)
        };
    }

    // POST api/Account/ChangePassword
    [Route("ChangePassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword,
            model.NewPassword);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/SetPassword
    [Route("SetPassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetPassword(SetPasswordBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/AddExternalLogin
    [Route("AddExternalLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddExternalLogin(AddExternalLoginBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(model.ExternalAccessToken);

        if (ticket == null || ticket.Identity == null || (ticket.Properties != null
            && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue
            && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow))
        {
            return BadRequest("External login failure.");
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalData = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(ticket.Identity);

        if (externalData == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("The external login is already associated with an account.");
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(),
            new UserLoginInfo(externalData.LoginProvider, externalData.ProviderKey));

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/RemoveLogin
    [Route("RemoveLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RemoveLogin(RemoveLoginBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result;

        if (model.LoginProvider == LocalLoginProvider)
        {
            result = await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
        else
        {
            result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                new UserLoginInfo(model.LoginProvider, model.ProviderKey));
        }

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ExternalLogin
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
        }

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        if (externalLogin == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (externalLogin.LoginProvider != provider)
        {
            Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            externalLogin.ProviderKey));

        bool hasRegistered = user != null;

        if (hasRegistered)
        {
            Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

             ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = externalLogin.GetClaims();
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            Authentication.SignIn(identity);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogins")]
    public IEnumerable<ExternalLoginViewModel> GetExternalLogins(string returnUrl, bool generateState = false)
    {
        IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> descriptions = Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
        List<ExternalLoginViewModel> logins = new List<ExternalLoginViewModel>();

        string state;

        if (generateState)
        {
            const int strengthInBits = 256;
            state = RandomOAuthStateGenerator.Generate(strengthInBits);
        }
        else
        {
            state = null;
        }

        foreach (AuthenticationDescription description in descriptions)
        {
            ExternalLoginViewModel login = new ExternalLoginViewModel
            {
                Name = description.Caption,
                Url = Url.Route("ExternalLogin", new
                {
                    provider = description.AuthenticationType,
                    response_type = "token",
                    client_id = Startup.PublicClientId,
                    redirect_uri = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, returnUrl).AbsoluteUri,
                    state = state
                }),
                State = state
            };
            logins.Add(login);
        }

        return logins;
    }

    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/RegisterExternal
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
    [Route("RegisterExternal")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterExternal(RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result); 
        }
        return Ok();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _userManager != null)
        {
            _userManager.Dispose();
            _userManager = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Helpers

    private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get { return Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    private IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (result.Errors != null)
            {
                foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private class ExternalLoginData
    {
        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public IList<Claim> GetClaims()
        {
            IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ProviderKey, null, LoginProvider));

            if (UserName != null)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName, null, LoginProvider));
            }

            return claims;
        }

        public static ExternalLoginData FromIdentity(ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            if (identity == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Claim providerKeyClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            if (providerKeyClaim == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerKeyClaim.Issuer)
                || String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerKeyClaim.Value))
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (providerKeyClaim.Issuer == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new ExternalLoginData
            {
                LoginProvider = providerKeyClaim.Issuer,
                ProviderKey = providerKeyClaim.Value,
                UserName = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)
            };
        }
    }

    private static class RandomOAuthStateGenerator
    {
        private static RandomNumberGenerator _random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        public static string Generate(int strengthInBits)
        {
            const int bitsPerByte = 8;

            if (strengthInBits % bitsPerByte != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("strengthInBits must be evenly divisible by 8.", "strengthInBits");
            }

            int strengthInBytes = strengthInBits / bitsPerByte;

            byte[] data = new byte[strengthInBytes];
            _random.GetBytes(data);
            return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(data);
        }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Comment: can anyone please tell me something?

Answer (score 0):

the logic to check the token should be somewhere in your startup.cs of the API project. Have a solution search for UseJwtBearerAuthentication and there the details should be specified.

The flow for the Authorize decoration goes 'automatically', using the properties set in UseJwtBearerAuthentication. If you want to do some additional checks, you are in need of a custom authorize attribute.

You should create a new class that inherits the interface AuthorizeAttribute. Implement the methods and you can do custom checks (such as checking against DB). Check this link to have a good example of custom authorize attributes:

https://mycodepad.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/mvc-custom-authorizeattribute-for-custom-authentication/

Be aware that with each call, your DB will be contacted which may imply some extra load.